# gpg won't use GNUPGHOME environment variable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, gnupg

I've set GNUPGHOME to '/somedir/gpg', and it *is* set, as `echo $GNUPGHOME` returns the correct value in both bash and zsh.
However, `gpg -h` still lists ~/.gpg as the homedir and it can't see my keys.
I would use the `--homedir` flag, but I'm trying to use `git commit -s`, so I can't specify it.

Comment: for now I'm using [this](https://gist.github.com/QuartzShard/2aa7eb6bdc39225f9790162657b57021) as a workaround, but it works normally on my laptop (also ubuntu), so I'd like to get to the bottom of it

Comment: Are you sure it is actually an _environment_ variable? That is, did you `export` it and does it show up in `env`?

Comment: It was under bash but not zsh. I look dumb as hell now lol

Answer (score 1):

Turns out while I had set it as an environment variable in bash, I'd forgotten to use export in zshrc.